# Java Return Type

Tags: java

If a method's return type is int and if it return's -1 what does it actually mean?

```
public int handle_get_multi_leg_net_quote(Message mmsg) throws Exception {          
        if (null != t) {
                     return 1;
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: `-1` is *integer*.

Comment: Yes ofcourse its an basic java question...but the idea behind posting is to know...whether thos code is done basedon some other languages...???because in java we have exceptions...then whats the need to throw -1 in specific...

Comment: It depends entirely on the design intent for the specific method. There is no such thing in Java as 'throw -1'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be a code written in another language, maybe it was supposed to be a boolean or even another type of data. One thing you could do is understand what it does in the other language before adapt it to Java.

Comment: Yes that is the reason i have posted the question...even though it is an silly and too basic java question.

Answer (score 4):

An [`int`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)eger in Java is **signed**, thus it's OK to return a negative number. This is typically used, in Java, for methods that need to return an integer, but *also* need to return an indication that something went *wrong*. For example, when [`String#indexOf(int ch)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29) does not find a certain character, it returns `-1` to indicate that it was not found.

However, in your particular method, I'd say it'd be more appropriate to return a `boolean` instead, or to throw an `Exception` when `t` is `null`. It's hard to say based on your example.

> **`int`**: The int data type is a 32-bit **signed** two's complement integer. It
>   has a minimum value of -2,147,483,648 and a maximum value of
>   2,147,483,647 (inclusive).

Comment: Yes ofcourse its an basic java question...but the idea behind posting is to know...whether thos code is done basedon some other languages...???because in java we have exceptions...then whats the need to throw -1 in specific?....

Comment: @user1367670: Of course, you're very welcome to ask questions here. In other languages, such as C, that don't directly support Exceptions, it's common to return `-1` to indicate an error. In Java, `Exception`s are more common like you said. In this situation, it doesn't make much sense to return `1` or `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is c code written in java. I think this should throw an exception and make use of Java's exception handling framework. I would think that this code is passing back -1 to indicate an error.

What should happen I think is

```
public int handleGetMultiLegNetQuote(Message mmsg) throws Exception {          
    if (null == t) {
         throws new IllegalArugmentExeption("null t");            
    }
     return 1;

}
```

I have also changed the method name to be in camelCase which is standard for java. 
Without more information it is difficult to see what is happening. Espeically as you check t which is not passed in to the method.

Although I could be completely wrong and it could just be passing back -1 which has some context in your code.

Answer (score 0):

int is 32 bits in Java. However, it's important to realize that only 31 of those bits actually contain the number. For example, Integer.MAX_VALUE returns 2^31 - 1, not 2^32 - 1. The most significant bit (the one furthest to the left) is a "sign" bit. It tells you if the number is positive or negative: a 0 means this is a positive number, a 1 means this is a negative number.

**So conclusion is** 
-1 is integer.

For details see a link:
http://radio.javaranch.com/corey/2004/04/12/1081786778000.html